# How to add clickable links in a Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mef, visual-studio-extensions

I'm attempting to create a Visual Studio (2015) Extension that turns certain text in code files into clickable links that open web URLs.

I've implemented an `IViewTaggerProvider` and an `ITagger` for it to return. I've implemented a tag that extends `IUrlTag` to return in the hopes that this tag would be automatically clickable.

The tagged text renders as a link (blue and underlined), but it doesn't react to being hovered or clicked.

What do I need to do to make the tagged text clickable?

**IViewTaggerProvider implementation**

```
[Export(typeof(IViewTaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("any")]
[TagType(typeof(JiraLinkTag))]
internal class JiraLinkTaggerProvider : IViewTaggerProvider
{
    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        //provide highlighting only on the top buffer   
        if (textView.TextBuffer != buffer)
            return null;

        return (ITagger<T>)new JiraLinkTagger(textView, buffer);
    }
}
```

The **ITagger** implementation is verbose, but it returns tags like this:

```
yield return new TagSpan<JiraLinkTag>(span, new JiraLinkTag(requestedSnapshot.GetText(span)));
```

**IUrlTag** implementation

```
internal class JiraLinkTag : IUrlTag
{
    public readonly string IssueKey;

    public JiraLinkTag(string issueKey)
    {
        IssueKey = issueKey;
    }

    public Uri Url
    {
        get { return new Uri(new Uri("https://JIRASERVER/browse/"), IssueKey); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I want to do the same thing that finds issue numbers in TODOs and creates a hyperlink to the JIRA webpage for that issue number.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't.